# C# Change password and lock the account

Tags: c#, authentication

I have to write a code that if you failed `5` login attempts, lock the user for `30` minutes.

This is the code for the login that counts the attempts

```
int InvalidLoginAttempts = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){
    Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
    string username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter password");
    string password = Console.ReadLine();

    if (username != "valid" || password != "valid")
        InvalidLoginAttempts++;
    else
        break;
}

if (InvalidLoginAttempts > 5)
    Console.WriteLine("Login failure");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Login successful");
Console.ReadKey();
```

How can I say that if `InvalidLoginAttempts > 5` the user will be locked?

Comment: InvalidLoginAttempts will be 5 when you exit the loop after 5 invalid attempts. So you should check if it's *equal* to 5  - or greater than or equal if you prefer that for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Why not *extract a method*? Instead of counting attempts, let's implement a simple loop within a simple method that returns `true` or `false`:

```
  private static bool TryToLogin(int attempts = 5) {
    for (int attempt = 0; attempt < attempts; ++attempt) {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
      string username = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Enter password");
      string password = Console.ReadLine(); 

      if (username == "valid" && password == "valid) 
        return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

All we have to do now is to check the value returned:

```
 if (!TryToLogin(5)) {
   //TODO: Lock user here

   Console.WriteLine("Login failure"); 
 }
 else {
   Console.WriteLine("Login successful");
 }
```

Comment: Good advice! And If I want to lock the user for 30 minutes?

Comment: @Matteo: before locking users, you have to solve these problems: 1. Where to store users and their locks. 2. How to *distinguish* one user from another? Imagine that I failed `5` times and then I restart the program with *different* login. What if *someone* failed with *my* login `5` times?